# Normalizing FFT after recording with Pyaudio

Tags: python, fft, pyaudio

I have a USB microphone that has a 24 bit ADC, however, Pyaudio doesn't allow for 24 bit encoding so I used 16 bit. I hope this is not an issue. Having said that, I hope to make sure I'm applying the Hanning window correctly and normalizing the FFT magnitudes correctly.

```
import numpy as np
import pyaudio
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.fftpack import fft
from scipy.io import wavfile # get the api
import wave

CHUNK = 2048
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 20480
RECORD_SECONDS = 34

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                input=True,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

n = CHUNK
k=np.arange(n)
T = n/RATE     #reciprocal of freq resolution
frq = k/T      #k* freq resolution
frq = frq[range(int(n/2))]    # one side frequency range, for plotting
freq_resolution=RATE/n        #frequency resolution 
window=np.hanning(n)          #Hanning window 
num_frames=int(RATE*RECORD_SECONDS/CHUNK)

for i in range(0, num_frames):
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    decoded = np.frombuffer(data, dtype=np.int16)
    windowed=window*decoded      #apply Hanning window
    fft_decode=fft(windowed)/(len(decoded)/2)
    mags=np.absolute(fft_decode) 

    plt.ylim(top=2)
    plt.xlabel('Freq (Hz)')
    plt.ylabel('|Y(freq)|')
    plt.plot(frq), mags[range(int(n/2))],'b') 
    plt.pause(.001)
    plt.gcf().clear()
plt.close()
```

I normalized the magnitude by (number of samples / 2) because I'm only interested in the one-sided plot, and I want the magnitude to correspond to the real signal. This means is the real signal is 5 sin(2pi*3000*t), I want a magnitude of 5 at the 3000hz one sided magnitude plot. If I divide by only the number of samples, it would give me half that value. Is this correct?

However, I also print out the maximum of the data (decoded), and the maximum of the fft magnitude for each iteration of the loop, and while they are mostly correlated, sometimes it doesn't. I might get a high maximum value for 'decoded' (say, 32000), but the maximum of the fft magnitude is no where near that. How is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: You might have better luck over on the DSP StackExchange.